# Task Dependency in Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a task in gulp that need to execute other two tasks consecutively and in order.

So when I run `build`, `build` run first `task-a`, when `task-a` is completed
`task-b` is performed.

At the moment I am using this script, I would like to have confirmation the is correct.

```
 gulp.task('build', [
        'task-a',
        'task-b'
    ]);
```

Comment: Yup, it'll run `task-a` then once that's completed it'll run `task-b`

Comment: No, it will run `task-a` and `task-b` in parallel - unless `task-b` internally defines `task-a` as a dep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated at the official documentation with that format the tasks [**will run in parallel (all at once), so don't assume that the tasks will start/finish in order**.](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulptaskname--deps-fn)

You have to explicitly define the order of tasks as follow to make Gulp workout the right order:

```
gulp.task('task-a', function(){ ... });

gulp.task('task-b', ['task-a'], function(){ ... });

gulp.task('build', ['task-a', 'task-b'], function(){ ... });
```

At this point when you'll try to run `build` Gulp will build the dependency tree of the tasks and workout that `task-b` relies on `task-a` to be completed before executing.

A more complete example can be found here: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-tasks-in-series.md

Comment: Thanks for explanation and example it solved my problem

Comment: This link is broken now, I think this is not the case anymore...

Answer (score 0):

The current gulp task you have at the moment will run correctly, it'll run `task-a` then run `task-b`. For whatever reason, it's not giving you back what you want. There's also an npm package called `run-sequence` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) you can use.

Your gulp task would look something like :

```
gulp.task('runTasks', function () {
    runSequence('task-a', 'task-b', 'task-c');
});
```

And that'll execute your tasks in the order sequence you pass it.

Comment: `The current gulp task you have at the moment will run correctly, it'll run task-a then run task-b.` Please correct this.