# Gulp create zip after all other tasks

Tags: gulp

I have a gulp file with a few different tasks. When I want to make a production build I run, `gulp.task('build', ['styles', 'uglify', 'copyScripts', 'copyImgs', 'copyFonts', 'compress']);`. The problem I am having is that I need the task `compress` to run after all others are finished.

Comment: Perhaps duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285269/task-dependency-in-gulp/34285442#34285442

Comment: That won't really work in my situation since I don't want compress to always have other tasks that need to run. I would like to be able to run gulp compress at will if desired.

Comment: Move the compress task content in a separate function, then call this function as callback of the "build" task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
function compressFn(){
  // write the code to compress here
}

// For backward compatibility with other tasks
gulp.task('compress', compressFn);

// It performs first all the tasks in the array THEN it calls compressFn
gulp.task('build', ['styles', 'uglify', 'copyScripts', 'copyImgs', 'copyFonts'], compressFn);
```